# Include instructions from other file in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to create a second file, for example Instructions.txt, and be able to include it's CMake instructions to the main CMakeLists.txt, for example:

```
// Instructions.txt
set(MY_VARIABLE value)
set(MY_SECOND_VARIABLE 1234)
```

```
// CMakeLists.txt
<HERE INCLUDE INSTRUCTIONS.TXT>

// And be able to use those variables, for example
project(MY_VARIABLE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do that simply by using another cmake.

Contrary to what you might believe, the file extension is different for other file than build files.

Let's call this file `instructions.cmake`:

```
set(MY_VARIABLE value)
set(MY_SECOND_VARIABLE 1234)
```

Then you can include it like this inside your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(instructions.cmake)
```

If the file is in the module path, you can include it like that:

```
include(instructions)
```

There are some other filename that are important for CMake though.

For example, any file that start with `Find` then ends with `.cmake` like `FindXYZ.cmake`, the `XYZ` part is assumed to be a package name and in that case you should use `find_package(XYZ REQUIRED)`.

Comment: It should be `include(instructions.cmake)` otherwise it would try to find a module `instructions.cmake` in module paths but would fail to do so.

Comment: @ixSci Ah you're right, let me correct that